# How to create an NPM package with Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2017

I like to create and deploy NPM packages with Visual Studio 2017.

I'm using TypeScript to create the JavaScript files.

What project template should I use for this project?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need Visual Studio to create a NPM package (it is a little disproportionate) but if you want to use it,  the best is the **basic html page template**.

For this king of project, for me the best is to use visual studio code and arrange the folders & subfolder as you want. You can look to other NPM project in github as Bootstrap for exemple to know how other users arrange their code.

I did a simple NPM package with TypeScript, you can have a look to my code organisation if you want :

https://github.com/AlexTeixeira/Askmethat-Rating